# Ubuntu is not recognizing CD-ROM

Tags: 11.10, cd-drive

When I insert a CD into my laptop running Ubuntu 11.10 nothing happens, there is no device showing that I have inserted the CD. I've read about mountind dev/cdrom and such but nothing of the sort seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried mounting it manually? **mkdir disc && sudo mount /dev/sg1 ./disc**

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to find CD/DVD drives available on your Ubuntu system

```
# wodim --devices
```

> Example

```
wodim --devices

wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW SH-S223F'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1st check it your cdrom is plugged in or not

Comment: 0  dev='/dev/sg1' rwrw-- : 'HL-DT-ST' 'DVDRAM GT30N'  ->  Then what?